# How to concat string in node js to call column

Tags: node.js

I wish to make call different column if user using different language, example in one collection I have description_en for English and description_ind for Indonesia.

The problem if I concat it is not working.

This is example code

```
let lang = req.params.lang;

order_status_description:element.orderstatus.description + lang,
```

this is my complete code

```
const MyOrderResource = (req,res,next)=>{
    let lang = req.params.lang;
    let arrayResult = [];
    req.order.forEach(element => {
        let arrayItem =[];

        element.orderitem.forEach(item=>{
            arrayItem.push({
                _id:item._id,
                product_id:item.product_id,
                product_name:item.product_name,
                description:item.description,
                unit:item.unit,
                price:item.price,
                fprice:'Rp ' + new Intl.NumberFormat().format(item.price),
                quantity:item.quantity,
                amount:item.amount,
                fprice:'Rp ' + new Intl.NumberFormat().format(item.amount),
            });
        });

        arrayResult.push({
            _id:element._id,
            user_id:element.user_id,
            date:element.date,
            store_id:element.store_id,
            store_name:element.profile[0].name,
            store_address:element.profile[0].address,
            total:element.total,
            ftotal:'Rp ' + new Intl.NumberFormat().format(element.total),
            order_status_code:element.orderstatus.code,
            order_status_description:element.orderstatus.description + lang,
            order_item:arrayItem,
        });
    });
    res.status(201).json({
        data:arrayResult,
        status : 200,
    })
}

module.exports = MyOrderResource;
```

For this code, I wish to call, column description_en, but the result is undefined

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you mean by, concat (`+`), is not working? Try to console the operated arguments and see their values, and console the operation (concat) result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
order_status_description : element.orderstatus["description" + lang]
```

In the posted snipet, it instructs to concat the **value** of key- 'element.orderstatus.description' to the **value** of key - 'lang'